# Is there any way to synchronize the Map Vector (OpenGL layer) and UIKit?

Tags: ios, google-maps, opengl-es, google-maps-sdk-ios

Say you have a fixed pin in the middle of the screen using an `UIImageView` on top of the `GMSMapView`. At some point in the flow I need to remove the fixed pin and add it as a marker in the map.

One could do so by setting the fixed pin `hidden` property to `true` and then adding a `GMSMarker` in the center of the map using the same asset as the `UIImageView`. That works except that there is a visual glitch since adding the marker touches the OpenGL layer whether hiding the pin uses `UIKit`.

Is there any way to synchronize these two operations?

Answer (score 1):

Not really. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12967340/2094275) for a discussion on OpenGL-UIKit syncing — the conclusion is that Apple has access to the private `CAEAGLLayer.synchronized` and nobody else does.

This is part of the reason why Google limits their SDK map views to 30fps, I'd imagine. Developing on top of a third-party SDK especially limits your syncing possibilities, as you have no/extremely-limited access to  `GLKView`, `CAEAGLLayer`, or `EAGLContext`.

I'd suggest investigating [Mapbox GL for iOS](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/) if you're looking for more wiggle-room and openness. See [this issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/1125) about ongoing efforts to improve inter-layer view syncing.