# How to interpret "precision" on glsl

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

From [What is the precision of highp floats in GLSL ES 2.0 (for iPhone/iPod touch/iPad)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414041/what-is-the-precision-of-highp-floats-in-glsl-es-2-0-for-iphone-ipod-touch-ipad) ...

I get, for instance, on the iPhone 5S, that highp float has a precision of "23". From the documentation (p. 33, section 4.5.2 — https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf ), I'm interpreting that as "the difference between two floating point numbers is at least 2^-23, which is 1.1920929e-7. But I'm fairly confident I'm not understanding that correctly, because I think I've got it calculating differences that are smaller than that by two or three orders of magnitude (and crapping out beyond that).

Am I just getting lucky with my calculations, or am I misunderstanding the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"The difference between two floating point numbers is at least 2^-23"* isn't quite correct.

From [the documentation](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetShaderPrecisionFormat.xml): "If the smallest representable value greater than *1* is *1+∊* then *floor(-log₂(∊))* is returned in `precision`."

So, what that means for you is that in your environment, the next representable number after 1 is (1+2^-23). This is not quite the same thing as saying that epsilon is always 2^-23 because floating point precision is [nonlinear](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) - the difference between nearest representable values depends on the magnitude of the values. If you read that article (which I recommend), note in particular the increase in density of representable values around zero, especially if the encoding permits denorms.

Comment: That was what I was afraid of (under the guise of "just getting lucky with my calculations"). Thanks! :) You wouldn't happen to have a suggestion for how to gauge whether I was hitting the density limit...?